# Does the blue highlight indicate anything?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have noticed that a few of my Pokemon have a blue highlight on them:

[image: Some Pokemon have a highlight]

From my inspection, I haven't been able to identify it's purpose. It doesn't distinguish CP, or if that Pokemon was caught or hatched, or even if that Pokemon is able to be leveled up or evolved.

Does it indicate anything?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It means that it is a newly acquired Pokémon. :)

Comment: Ah yes! I reordered them to most recent and they all grouped together at the top of the list :)

Comment: How new is "newly acquired"? 12 hours? 24?

Comment: @Pyritie it could be until you view the details on it (IE: click on it). I have some highlighted in my list from over 48 hours ago.

Comment: @RianBattle It's definitely not just that -- there's loads of stuff in my list that I'm sure I've seen the details of several times, yet they still have the blue background.